# How can i get total of distinct value correct?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using powerbi to represent the distinct count of each browser .

and at the end I want total of all of them which is coming wrong.

[image]

See the total is coming wrong.

I am using this formula

**Count of Unique PERSON_ID =

SUMX(DISTINCT('USAGE'[BROWSER]),
 DISTINCTCOUNT('USAGE'[PERSON_ID]))**

What i am doing wrong ?  New to Powerbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
  Count of Unique PERSON_ID = 
          SUMX(DISTINCT('USAGE'[BROWSER]),  
          CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('USAGE'[PERSON_ID])))
```

Comment: God bless you... after hours of work.... may god bless you